# Lua (Corona SDK) Android issue - interval is empty

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

On PC, my game compiles fine and runs properly, but as soon as I build it for Android I get this weird error code:

```
bad argument #1 to 'random' (interval is empty)
```

The line of code this error code comes from is:

```
local word = wordsList[math.random(#wordsList)]
```

The whole code Segement:

```
local lineCount = 1
local wordsList = {}
local wordAccepted = true
local file = io.open( system.pathForFile( "words.txt", system.ResourceDirectory ), "r" ) --Open the words file from the resource folder
for line in file:lines() do 
    if #line > 1 and #line <= 10 then 
        for i = 1,#line do
            if string.byte(line,i)<65 or string.byte(line,i)>90 and string.byte(line,i)<97 or string.byte(line,i)>122 then 
                wordAccepted = false
            end
        end
        if wordAccepted == true then
            print ("accepted "..line) 
            wordsList[lineCount]=string.upper(line) 
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
        else
            print("rejected "..line)
        end
    end
end
io.close( file )
file = nil
local word = wordsList[math.random(#wordsList)]
```

Comment: What is `wordsList`? How big is it?

Comment: I tried the wordsList at sizes 3 and 78. Both had the same issue

Comment: Provide a small example of `wordsList`.

Comment: wordsList is just an array of words taken from a "words.txt" file in the resource folder. When I tried wordsList with 3 words (A,B,C) the issue still remained. I'm just trying to pick a random word from that wordsList and set it to a new word variable.

Comment: Don't just describe the code, show it. Like `local wordsList = {"A", "B", "C"}`.

Comment: Ok I put the whole code part in the main post, hope that helps.

Comment: In your PC first clear the sandbox and check whether the same issue occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `bad argument #1 to 'random' (interval is empty)` means that you are trying to pass zero to `math.random()`.
In other words, your `wordsList` array is empty.

Comment: Any idea why this would only be an issue on PC? Could it be that on Android it can't read the text file or can't access it in some way?

Comment: Probably, on your Android system the file `words.txt` is empty or incorrect or not the same as on PC.